# Using two different email fo sending eemail in Django

Tags: django, django-settings, django-mailer

I want to use two email, one for verifying the email and other for sending normal informative emails. I am able to send email for verification with the following code and I want to use my another email for that second perpose.

views.py

```
    current_site = get_current_site(request)
    subject = 'Welcome to MySite! Confirm Your email.'
    htmly     = get_template('account_activation_email.html')

    d = { 'user': user, 'domain':current_site.domain, 'uemail':urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user.email)), 'uid':urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user.pk)), 'token': account_activation_token.make_token(user)}

    text_content = ""
    html_content = htmly.render(d)
    msg = EmailMultiAlternatives(subject, text_content, '', [user.email])
    msg.attach_alternative(html_content, "text/html")
    try:
        msg.send()
    except BadHeaderError:
        print("Error while sending email!")
    user.save()
```

and in settings:

```
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = config('EMAIL_HOST')
EMAIL_HOST_USER = verify@mysite.com
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'randompass'
EMAIL_PORT = config('EMAIL_PORT')
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'MySte Verification <verify@mysite.com>'
```

Please help!!!

Comment: If you use something like SendGrid you can specify the from email address differently for each email type (but using the same API/password).

Comment: i am using godaddy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a different email to be send as "To email", just add the different email in the param. More information here [Django Email](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/email/).

If you want a different email server that sends the emails, consider making your own [email backend](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/email/#email-backends) that based on specific methods/functions/params uses that specific email server you're looking for. For example:

```
from django.core.mail import get_connection, send_mail
from django.core.mail.message import EmailMessage

with get_connection(
    host=my_host, 
    port=my_port, 
    username=my_username, 
    password=my_password, 
    use_tls=my_use_tls
) as connection:
    EmailMessage(subject1, body1, from1, [to1],
                 connection=connection).send()
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: so i need to do the with block everytime i want to send an email?? Also i am using EmailMultiAlternatives to send the mail.

Comment: You can use any send email method  as if you look at the documentation you’ll see that the accept a connection parameter. Also don’t always include this block. Just create a method that accepts specific parameters and define the extra email server information in your settings.py. If you wish to see a example let me know and I’ll edit the answer so you can see :)